# Add a local variable to every row of a result set

Tags: sql, t-sql

I've been playing around with a large database on which I'm done many summary statistics.  I can't help but think there's got to be a quicker way than what I'm doing.

Take for instance the following query:

```
select count(*), thing1, thing2, thing3 from myTable
group by thing1, thing2, thing3
```

[image]

The 1=true and 0=false.  If I wanted to add a a local variable from the dataset (say `select @total=count(*) from peopleTable`) and divided each row in counts by @total, is there a typical SQL solution for this?  I know how to do this on a per-row basis, but not all at once like this.

Comment: I don't understand your question at all. You want to get a total count of all rows and you want to devide each count for each row by total count? If so you can just use your predefined @total in your select like SELECT Count(*) / '@total, ...

Comment: In the first row 0, 0, 0 indicates someone who does not have 1, 2 or 3.  I would like for the entire population to be in a column to the right of thing3 (select count(*) from thatTable, and then another column that divdes counts by the total people in the dataset

Comment: edited the proposed result set for clarity

Comment: You can do a '@total = SELECT and use this in your second SQL or you work with a SUBSELECT. If you can do 2 SELECTS in your case, do so, it is better instead of get for each row a subselect

Comment: I'm new enough to SQL that I'm just learning the basics.  I'm mainly looking for how one would add a variable of interest to every row of a result set, just to see the mechanics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDITED:

Now I think you want this:

```
DECLARE @total int;
SET @total = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM peopleTable)
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_column
     , CAST(COUNT(*) AS float) / @total AS percent_total
     , @total AS total_ppl
     , thing1, thing2, thing3 
FROM myTable
GROUP BY thing1, thing2, thing3
```

This query give you COUNT of your grouped records, percentage count regarding to total ppl and total ppl.

Comment: the first option is very close and looks close to what I need (although i had to do 100 * count(*).  but this still doesn't add the @totalpop to the end of every row.

Comment: And imho don't do a 100* ... 1 = 100% so your result is ok, and if you want to format it e.g. in a sql report your format percentage there.

Comment: In my real case and not test case it's 73000

Comment: if i didn't add the 100* then the answer returned was 0 for every column.  I suppose the count(*) should be cast as float?

Comment: @wootscootinboogie exactly. CAST(COUNT(*) AS float) to get correct value then. But I still don't get what you miss as total column for each row now.

Comment: the column in the picture total ppl to appear on every row. if there were 10,000 records in peopleTable then that number should appear on every row

Comment: Edited my post and added @total as another column.